# Large factorial number divisibility

Tags: divisibility, factorial

How can I proof that 14! is not divisible by 3<sup>6</sup>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $4=\lfloor 14/3\rfloor$ multiples of $3$ and $1=\lfloor 14/9\rfloor$ multiple of $9$.

Hence $3^5$ divides $14!$ but $3^6$ does not.

Comment: [cough] how many multiples of 9?

Comment: @Joffan  Ops! :P

Answer (score 1):

Count the factors of $3$ that appear.  You get one from each multiple of $3$ except two from multiples of $9$ (and, if your factorial were larger, three from multiples of $27$, etc.)  How many do you get?  Another approach is to [ask Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%2014!) and get $14!=87178291200 = 2^{11}×3^5×5^2×7^2×11×13 $

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
14! = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdots13\cdot14\\
= 2\cdot3\cdot2^2\cdot5\cdot(2\cdot3)\cdots13\cdot(2\cdot7)\\
= 2^{11}\cdot3^{?}\cdot5^2\cdot7^2\cdot11\cdot13
$$
Just count the number of $3$'s you get in line two above.